# Cannot change permissions for SMB share

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba

I am having a permissions issue and looking for some guidance, I have installed sonarr which the sonarr user needs to be able to write to a SMB network share I have setup. I cannot seem to change the permissions on it so sonarr user can write to it. I cannot change the permissions on the client at all so I assume this is a config error or I am mounting the share wrong.

Permissions for the share on the host VM

`drwxrwxrwx+  7 veemo veemo  4096 Apr  2 12:31 Plexmedia3`

Permissions from the mounted share on the client VM

`drwxr-xr-x 2 veemo veemo    0 Apr  2 12:31 Plexmedia3`

SMB config:

```
[Plexmedia3]
path = /media/veemo/Plexmedia3
guest ok = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
public = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

fstab mount:

```
//<internal IP>/Plexmedia3 /media/veemo/Plexmedia3 cifs uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Comment: My `pathlld` script might help `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing here. Are you doing a cifs mount of a share on the same system?